# Caffe deploy error

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to load my net, but when I try to load deploy.txt caffe gives me the following error:

```
Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 64:7: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "layer".
```

This is my [deploy.prototxt](https://bpaste.net/show/5559ed1f70a1)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 63 you have a missing `}`

Just change to this:

```
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, thank you Caaarlos, I'm on this problem for 3h hahaha.